# Rebase on existing `git` history with `git svn`

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I have a `git` repo which I made some commits in. An existing group of developers copy/pasted its files into an `svn` repo, and then invited me onto their team to work. So, the `svn` history starts with the latest commit in my `git` history. I want to add the missing history.

Using `git svn`, I did this:

```sh
git svn clone https://their-svn-repo.com/ theirs
cd theirs
git pull ../my-existing-git-repo
```

which works nicely, and inserts the missing history at the beginning of their repo.

[image: gitk visualized history graph]

But, when I try to do `git svn dcommit` or `git svn rebase`, I get an error:

```sh
$ git svn dcommit
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 870.


$ git svn rebase
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

[There's an article](https://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/01/04/commit-a-linear-git-history-to-subversion/) which addresses a similar issue, although it assumes that the `svn` repo is empty and also uses the "standard" `svn` layout, which this repo doesn't.

I know it's a bit of a weird case, but anybody know how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can dcommit by moving refs/remotes/git-svn to the master branch with the following command.

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn master
git checkout master
git svn dcommit
```